# C++ map :first call to map[a], how to initialize map[a].second to zero?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

When I use operator[] to call `map[a];` while there is no key a in the map will the second element in `map[a]`be initialized to zero? If not, are there any good way to do it? I'm currently using `if (map.find(a)) map[a]++; else map[a] = 1;`. I want to use a map that is initialized to 0 and calling only `map[a]++;` and `map[a]--;`

Comment: "while there is no key a in the map will the second element in map[a]be initialized to zero?" It depends on the type of the map.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh I see. I looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/ and I think it is not quite clear.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's only the link named `at`, if you follow it you'll get the reference for `operator[]`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yep, sorry!

Comment: note that `find` will return an iterator, and returns `end` if nothing is found. you need to compare with `end` for the `if` to work.

Comment: @sp2danny Thanks! I completely forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a map with a type such as `std::map<int, int> m`, then a call to `m[a]` for a non-existent key `a` will insert an element with key `a` and value `int()`, that is, `0`. So you can safely simplify your code to

```
std::map<int, int> m

....

m[a]++; // OK
```

In the general case, the new element insertion inserts a *value initialized* key object to the map. For built-in arithmetic types such as `int`, value initialization means zero initialization.

Comment: So `int a()` will leave a = 0 but `int a` will leave the value in a undefined right?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin `int a()` is a function declaration. `int a = int();` or `int a{}` leaves `a` zero initialized. `int a` leaves it uninitialized if it is an automatic variable (the most usual case.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `std::map`, if `operator[]` creates a new element (i.e. for a key that doesn't previously exist, then the mapped value is value initialised.

For basic types like `int`, that means a value of zero.   For class/class types, it means default construction.